# Sql gruoup by clause not fetching desired result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQl table:

```
    Item_id     city_product_id                            auto_inc   price     

1.   XYZ         CHDELCLAPTOPDELLINSPIRON                   1          1500   
2.   ABCD        CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816                   2          1200
3.   ABCD        CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816                   3          1000
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
 SELECT city_product_id, item_id, auto_inc, MIN( price ) AS minPrice
 FROM sellers_product GROUP BY city_product_id
```

This query is returning this output:

```
   city_product_id           item_id       auto_inc     price     

   CHDELCLAPTOPDELLINSPIRON  XYZ               1        1500

   CHDELCLAPTOPDELLVOSTR816  ABCD              2        1000
```

**The only problem is why it is returning auto_inc as 2 when it should return 3 because 1000 is less than 1200.**

Comment: Try to include `auto_inc` in Group by Clause as well.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No it didn't work

Comment: Here is a way to do it, change as per your need http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/385f0/3

Comment: include Item_id as well.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Why should I want to fetch results by descending order?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Could you plz tell me query corresponding to my table

Comment: So I've removed the MSSQL tag

Comment: @AK2 check the answer from MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non aggregated fields in presence of group by will give indeterminate results you can use a self join to determine the correct row with minimum price

```
SELECT p.*
 FROM sellers_product p
join (select city_product_id,MIN( price ) AS minPrice 
      from sellers_product 
      GROUP BY city_product_id) p1
on(p.city_product_id = p1.city_product_id and p.price = p1.minPrice )
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf1532/1)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's group-by function uses the first-encountered row to fill in a value for any non-grouped field in a result row.

```
SELECT city_product_id, item_id, auto_inc, price 
from ( SELECT *
       FROM sellers_product      
       ORDER BY price ASC) AS h
GROUP BY city_product_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d5b2/1

Comment: One of the worst features of MySQL, yuk!